# Problem when mock class Using jest with constructor method

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I am a new with unit test using Jest.
This is my Account class

```
....
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
module.exports = {
  Account,
};
```

This is my accountService

```
function createAccount(data) {
  const account = new Account(user_id: data.user_id);
}
```

This is my accountService.test

```
const { createAccount } = require('../../src/service/accountService')
const { Account } = require('../../src/models/Account');

jest.mock('../../src/models/Account', () => ({
  Account: {
    create: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    find: jest.fn(),
  }
}));

describe('Test function', () => {
  it('Run create account function', async () => {
    const result = await createAccount({
      user_id: 1,
    });
    expect(result).toEqual('');
  });
});
```

However when I run it, an error appears

```
TypeError: Account is not a constructor
```

Please teach me how to fix it and how to mock account ? Thank for your attention.

Comment: `Account` _isn't_ a constructor, it's just an object. Your test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing - you could use e.g. a function (_not_ an arrow function) that returns the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Account` model is a class, but you mocked it as an object. Here is the solution:

`account.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const AccountSchema = new Schema({ name: String, user_id: Number });
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

module.exports = {
  Account,
};
```

`accountService.js`:

```js
const { Account } = require('./account');

async function createAccount(data) {
  const account = new Account({ user_id: data.user_id });
  await account.save();
}

module.exports = { createAccount };
```

`accountService.test.js`:

```js
const { createAccount } = require('./accountService');

const accountDocument = {
  save: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
  find: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock('./account', () => ({
  Account: jest.fn(() => accountDocument),
}));

describe('Test function', () => {
  it('Run create account function', async () => {
    await createAccount({ user_id: 1 });
    expect(accountDocument.save).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68831298/accountService.test.js (9.378 s)
  Test function
    ✓ Run create account function (2 ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 accountService.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.339 s, estimated 12 s
```